# How to create a new dataframe with an average of panel data with different IDs and times?

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a dataset, `df` that looks as follows:

| Date | Code | City | State | Ranking |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 0.852 |
| 2020-02 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 0.945 |
| 2020-03 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 0.991 |
| 2020-01 | 20002 | Houston | TX | 0.134 |
| 2020-02 | 20002 | Houston | TX | 0.234 |
| 2020-03 | 20002 | Houston | TX | 0.667 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 2021-07 | 10001 | Los Angeles | CA | 0.678 |
| 2021-07 | 20002 | Houston | TX | 0.721 |

I have multiple cities, each city containing a `Ranking` that ranges from `2020-01` to `2021-07`. I want to create a new dataframe, where I take the average of each city's ranking over time. Essentially, my new data set would be:

| Code | Average Ranking |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | 0.8665 |
| 20002 | 0.439 |

I have no idea how to extract my information. The closest thing I thought about doing was still not giving me the right output:

```
df_avg = df.groupby(['Code','Date'],as_index=False)['Ranking'].mean().rename(columns={'Ranking':'Avg_Ranking'})
```

How can I create this new data frame, `df_avg`, with two columns, `Code` and `Average Ranking`, where `Average Ranking` is the mean `Ranking` for each `Code`?

Comment: What happens if you remove `Date` from your groupby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `Date` from your groupby key. In this case, you want the mean value of column `Ranking` from all rows in each `Code` column, so your groupby key should be only `Code`.

```py
df_avg = df.groupby(['Code'],as_index=False)['Ranking'].mean().rename(columns={'Ranking':'Avg_Ranking'})
```